# The Reals, Complex Numbers and Quaternions

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis

What is an acceptable way to refer the set of objects that consists of the reals, complex numbers and quaternions?

Comment: The quaternions?

Comment: The associative division algebras over the real numbers?

Comment: You are looking for the associative [division algebras](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DivisionAlgebra.html)

Comment: $\{\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}, \mathbb{H}\}$

Comment: Define "acceptable", please.

Answer (score 1):

these are the (finite dimensional) associative division algebras over $\mathbb R$. If you drop associative, you can include the [octonians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octonion) and if you drop the [alternative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternative_algebra) requirement, we have the [sedonians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sedenion).

Comment: What does "even less associative" mean?

Comment: @celtschk in the sense that it is not even alternative